# Chrome Developer Tools - Emulate CSS Media no Checkbox

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Not sure if this is an error, but I can't active the print view in Chrome Developer Toolbar:

As you can see, the checkbox is missing:

[image]

I have Version 64.0.3282.186

Comment: Did you find  a workaround? I have the same problem in Chrome v65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that they changed the user experience in chrome. So there is no checkbox, since you just don't need it. Just change the selectbox under the "Emulate CSS media" and it works.

IMHO: I think this UI change is not very consistent, but ok.

EDIT: You might have to reload your site.

Comment: It's not working for me. I don't see any changes although I have created some rules for print media queries. I just posted the issue in Google Chrome Help Forum.

Comment: Tried to reload after changing selectbox?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me without checkbox. But it was really confusing, I'm not sure why they did that. And my post on Chrome forum is still unanswered!